# I checked the heroku logs and I saw an unexpected error no such file to load -- ./astute

Tags: sinatra

SSup Whizz people!!! I've deployed a simple_fb_app on heroku. When I heroku open the app page( https://astute.heroku.com/) it says application error. I checked the heroku logs and I saw an unexpected error

> no such file to load -- ./astute . Please help me solve this i'l buy
>   you beer -:)

MY GEMFILE HAS

```
gem 'sinatra', '1.0'
gem 'oa-oauth', '0.1.6'
GEM
```

MY GEMFILE LOCK HAS

```
remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.2.8)
    faraday (0.5.7)
      addressable (~> 2.2.4)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.1.0, < 2)
    multi_json (0.0.5)
    multipart-post (1.1.5)
    nokogiri (1.4.7-x86-mingw32)
    oa-core (0.1.6)
      rack (~> 1.1)
    oa-oauth (0.1.6)
      multi_json (~> 0.0.2)
      nokogiri (~> 1.4.2)
      oa-core (= 0.1.6)
      oauth (~> 0.4.0)
      oauth2 (~> 0.1.0)
    oauth (0.4.6)
    oauth2 (0.1.1)
      faraday (~> 0.5.0)
      multi_json (~> 0.0.4)
    rack (1.4.1)
    sinatra (1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  oa-oauth (= 0.1.6)
  sinatra (= 1.0)
```

THIS IS MY config.ru

- require './astute'   #this is to load astute.rb

  run Sinatra::Application

THIS IS MY astute.rb

```
require 'sinatra'         #required for framework detection in heroku.
require 'omniauth/oauth'

enable :sessions
disable :show_exceptions

#Here you have to put your own Application ID and Secret
APP_ID = "429085837122498"
APP_SECRET = "2232ac2dd09f452a015f9f00083da8e3"

use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, APP_ID, APP_SECRET, { :scope => 'email, status_update, publish_stream' }
end

get '/' do
    @articles = []
    @articles << {:title => 'Deploying Rack-based apps in Heroku', :url => 'http://docs.heroku.com/rack'}
    @articles << {:title => 'Learn Ruby in twenty minutes', :url => 'http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/'}

    erb :index
end

get '/auth/facebook/callback' do
  session['fb_auth'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  session['fb_token'] = session['fb_auth']['credentials']['token']
  session['fb_error'] = nil
  redirect '/'
end

get '/auth/failure' do
  clear_session
  session['fb_error'] = 'In order to use this site you must allow us access to your Facebook data<br />'
  redirect '/'
end

get '/logout' do
  clear_session
  redirect '/'
end

def clear_session
  session['fb_auth'] = nil
  session['fb_token'] = nil
  session['fb_error'] = nil
end
```

Comment: What does the `require` statements in your app file say? And is there an `astute.rb` file in your app directory?

Comment: Yes there is an astute.rb file in my app directory 

You can git clone it here
git clone git@heroku.com:astute.git -o heroku

Answer (score 0):

Your config.ru should be :

```
  require './astute'

  run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: Iam afraid my config.ru is exactly like that, but it doesnt seem to work. 
Additionaly it brings me this error when I open it in the local host
ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for nil:N